# how to obtain this solution for first order ode when integral does not have solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given ode $y^{\prime}=y+y^{2}+\sin y$ with initial conditions $y\left(
1\right)  =0$. This is just quadrature whose solution is

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dy}{y+y^{2}+\sin y}  & =\int dx\\
\int^{y\left(  x\right)  }\frac{dz}{z+z^{2}+\sin z}  & =x+c_{1}
\end{align*}

Since the integral on the LHS can't be evaluated. The question now is how
come the solution comes out to be $y\left(  x\right)  =0$ when applying the
initial conditions? This is the part I am having hard time with. According to
Maple and Mathematica the solution is $y\left(  x\right)  =0$ when applying
the IC.

But when $y\left(  1\right)  =0$ the above becomes

\begin{align*}
0  & =1+c_{1}\\
c_{1}  & =-1
\end{align*}

Hence the solution is

$$
\int^{y\left(  x\right)  }\frac{dz}{z+z^{2}+\sin z}=x-1
$$

How to obtain that $y\left(  x\right)  =0$ is the solution from the above? What technique or reasoning that lead to this solution?

[image]

Comment: Notice that when $y=1$, $y'=0$, so the solution is constant.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, *$y=0$

Comment: @whpowell96  why do you say when $y=0$ then $y'=0$? the $y=0$ is the instantaneous value of $y$ at the initial conditions point. It does not means its derivative is necessarily zero. right? Function could still have slope not zero, even if its value is zero at one point. I know that $y(x)=0$ is a solution to the ode, but it is a _trivial_ solution. I am asking is how this was obtained from the general solution I showed.  Is it OK to return the trivial solution like this? I assumed Maple found this solution from the general solution.

Comment: Since $y$ satisfies the given differential equation, once you know the value of $y$ at a point, you know the value of $y'$ at that point as well. In this case, $y(x)=0\implies y'(x)=0$.

Comment: @whpowell96 oh, I see now. So Maple did not find the solution from the general one!  It used short cut like you did. so it found that `y(x)=constant` and now it substituted the IC. I thought all the time it used the general solution with that tricky integral.  OK. But does this not give the solution only at that point?  i.e. `y'=0` only at the initial conditions. not everywhere. So I am still not clear how `y(x)=0` is the solution everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the solution
$$
\int_{y(x_0)}^{y(x)}\frac{dz}{z+z^{2}+\sin z}   =x-x_0 \tag{1}
$$
is ill-defined if $y(x_0)=0$, as the integral on the LHS of $(1)$ diverges. In this case, as remarked by @whpowell96, the solution to the ODE is $y(x)=0$, which cannot be derived from $(1)$.

Comment: As I mentioned in comments above. I still do not see how $y(x)=0$ was obtained from the general solution. I see it is trivial solution ok. I also see that at only initial  conditions, $y'=0$ which gives `y=constant` and when plugging in the initial conditions, gives $y=0$. but this solution is only at one point (the initial conditions). My question is still, why is $y=0$ everywhere?  could not the solution be different from its value at IC? I am trying to find the logic how `y(x)=0` is the solution everywhere (other than it being trivial solution)

Comment: Would you be able to explain also what you mean by **ill-defined if y(x0)=0
, as the integral on the LHS of (1)  diverges**  Since the integral is has no known anti-derivative, I am confuse why you say it diverges?

Comment: Is it better to write the general solution as $$
\int^{y\left(  x\right)  }\frac{dz}{z+z^{2}+\sin z}=x-x_0
$$ vs. what you wrote $$
\int_{y(x_0)}^{y(x)}\frac{dz}{z+z^{2}+\sin z}   =x-x_0 \tag{1}
$$ Just wondering if there is some standard to follow here.

Comment: (1) Maybe the "general solution" is not so general. To obtain it, you divided $y'$ by $y+y^2+\sin y$, but this division is not well-defined if $y=0$. On the other hand, one can verify, by direct substitution in the ODE, that $y(x)=0$ is a solution that satisfies the initial condition $y(1)=0$. (Whether this solution is unique or not is another question.) (2) I don't know its anti-derivative, but I know that, for $z\to 0$, the integrand can be approximated by $(2z)^{-1}$, so the integral diverges if the lower limit of integration is zero.

Comment: (3) I prefer to write both limits of integration: the lower one corresponding to the initial condition, the other one corresponding to a generic $x$. They are both necessary in the case of a numerical integration.